# How does maven know which repo to use for a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, repository

First off, I searched google but cant seem to find an answer for this. Apologies if its an obvious answer.

In maven we can define 0 or more repositories where it looks for resources. Repositories can be defined in settings.xml or within your pom. By default if you define no repositories everything will come from a repository name 'central' which is just the default one maintained by maven.

The below setup pom snippet comes from the jboss eap sample apps. When I do a mvn clean install I can see some things are pulled from central and some from the jboss repos. There does not seem to be anything in the dependency tag that tells maven which repository contains the dependency so how does it decide? Is it some how tied to group ID in the dependency or does maven just check all the repos one by one till it finds the first one that contains the jar?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/qa/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository-ea</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: By resolving the most recent version available from the list of repositories. For enterprise development, or even sane versioning, you want to version your dependencies (and use only managed internal repositories so you can control licensing and approvals on third party licenses).

Comment: You are required to specify a version from what I know. When you don't specify a version maven will throw a validation error. Its omitted above since there is a dependency management tag section that specifies the version in a parent pom. Since it does not pertain to my question I wanted to keep the post simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven just goes through the list and looks into all the repositories.

It is not possible to tie dependencies to special repositories.

Comment: Do you have a source for this or its just common knowledge. That seems to be proven out by what I am seeing. I think even libraries that should be in maven central are coming from the jboss repo. Must be some things missing in jboss repo since I still see a few calls to maven central.

Comment: will go ahead and mark this as accepted answer - thanks! But if you happen to have a source that would be nice as well.

Answer (score 6):

Lets take a look at the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html):

> Remote repository URLs are queried in the following
> order for artifacts until one returns a valid result:
>
> 1. Effective settings:
>
> - Global `settings.xml`
> - User `settings.xml`
>
> 2. Local effective build POM:
>
> - Local pom.xml
> - Parent POMs, recursively
> - Super POM
>
> 3. Effective POMs from dependency path to the artifact.
>
> For each of these
> locations, the repositories within the profiles are queried first in
> the order outlined at Introduction to build profiles.
>
> Before downloading from a repository, mirrors configuration is
> applied.
>
> Effective settings and local build POM, with profile taken into
> account, can easily be reviewed to see their repositories order with
> `mvn help:effective-settings` and `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose`.